# How to run multiple scripts of Jmeter in a batch

Tags: jmeter

I am using the Jmeter tool for the performance testing.

We have recorded the scripts for each scenario and now we would like to run them in a group in order to simulate the real time scenario.

Could any one please let me know how can we run all the scenarios in one go? Is there any procedure to group all the scenarios that I have recorded and give load on the sever at same time?

Please let me know the steps if any.

Comment: Do you have multiple .jmx files?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a single file with one thread group for each scenario, and set the testplan to run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

If your test plans are all separate currently and you want to keep them that way, there's always the option of a second device (or a third, or a fourth...). You won't have a single consolidated report of performance -- but you will get the performance for each plan you run separately.

This can also be a good option if,

a) One load client can't produce enough of the desired load for all your test plans running at once, and

b) you don't want to use the [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) features of JMeter to run the test plan from multiple load clients at once.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my solution for the same problem.
For running multiple .jmx files I have:

1. folder with all the jmx filed grouped as needed
2. runner - batch file with the following:

   `dir ..\Jmx\*.jmx /s /b /A:-D > ..\runner\data.txt
   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (data.txt) do %JMETER_HOME%\jmeter -n -t %%A -Jusers=10         -Jrampup=5 -Jloop=10 -Jport=[port] -Jserver=[server] -l [folder]\Results.csv
   exit`

[see general structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlXyM.png)